# 3ds Max: Trying to reduce polygons in multiple objects, while others are automatically adding

Tags: 3ds-max, modeling

So here's my bike model and I'm trying to reduce the amount of polygons in multiple objects by using ProOptimizer. The problem is that every time I'm clicking calculate, then reduce the amount of vertex in % and just after I click on other object to reduce vertex %, the previous, or any other that got reduced already, reset and goes back to original polygons amount. Under the calculate button a message appears saying: "Optimization Invalid"
I really need to make the model to have below or exactly 5000 Polygons!

[image: Here is how it looks like]

Comment: Hello Brian, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. 3D questions are a bit of an uneasy fit on this site. They aren't off-topic *per se*, but we have very little users with 3D expertise who will be able to answer your question. Please do have a look at the [Area 51 proposal for a 3D Graphics SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics), which could really use your help! If you have any questions about GD.SE, have a look at the [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's nothing easy about this. Polygon reduction is a bit of an art, in and of itself, and the more you learn about polygon modelling the more you'll understand about reduction. This is unfortunate because most people need the polygon reduction first, from commercial models.

Some steps to understanding how to solve this particular problem:

1. Turn the model into a Polygon model, instead of a Mesh model
2. Separate the objects/parts of the bike out into individual objects so you can add modifiers to them and make changes independently.
3. Add the optimiser modifier to each object and experiment with reduction...

Long story short: learning how to do polygon modelling will help you realise optimisers are wildly guessing things that have little to no hope of being truly helpful. After decades of 3D tools of this sort, custom modelling by professional modellers is still an enormous part of 3D game content creation. People compromise between model fidelity/quality and polygon counts better than algorithms can. That's probably not going to change anytime soon.